# cypher multiple match is very slow

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to match some node which don't satisfy the condition, but it's very slow. How to optimize it? There are about 70000 nodes in the database.

```
match (n:A)--(p:B)--(q:C)
with collect(n) as nc 
match m where not m in nc 
return count(m)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to first get all the nodes that match an initial pattern. It is enough to go through all the nodes and check them:

```
MATCH (m) WHERE NOT (m)--(:B)--(:C)
RETURN count(m)
```

Or if the condition on the label 'A' is important:

```
MATCH (m) 
OPTIONAL MATCH p = (m)--(:B)--(:C)
WITH m WHERE (p IS NULL) OR (NOT p IS NULL AND NOT 'A' IN LABELS(m))  
RETURN count(m)
```